# How to install pandas for Python 3?

Tags: python, pandas, installation, pip, python-3.4

I try to install pandas for Python 3 by executing the following command:

```
sudo pip3 install pandas
```

As a result I get this:

```
Downloading/unpacking pandas
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pandas
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pandas
```

Maybe it is interesting to note that installation for Python 2 works fine.

```
sudo pip install pandas
```

Returns the following:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pandas in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz>=2011k in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.6.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pandas)
Cleaning up...
```

ADDED

I have just installed pandas in the following way:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pandas
```

Comment: What happens if you try `sudo python3 -m pip install pandas` ? I find `pip3` to behave funny sometimes.

Comment: I've installed `pip3` via `brew` and `pip3 install pandas` works like a charm. You problem is probably distribution dependent which one are you using?

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo -H pip3 install pandas
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me, finally:

```
pip3 install pandas --no-build-isolation
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe for Python 3.4 you should use: `pip3 install 'pandas<0.21'`.
Don't forget, if your machine requires a proxy, add this bit after install: `--proxy=http://sub_domain_proxy.sub_domain.domain:port`

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time, pip gives me errors (I really don't know why), so I use apt-get instead.

For python3 use:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pandas
```

For python2 use:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pandas
```