# Module not found error in Python while trying to import pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to import pandas on Python (Linux) but it is giving me the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError
>   Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   1 import pandas as pd
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: did you install pandas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install pandas for Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768996/how-to-install-pandas-for-python-3)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481974/importerror-no-module-named-pandas)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try below code to install pandas.

```
sudo pip3 install pandas
```

Above code work for me .

Answer (score 2):

Try installing with this:

```
pip install pandas
```

If the install fails due to lacking privilege, do this:

```
sudo pip install pandas
```

**Note: You may have to use pip3 is your default Python version is 2.X**

Answer (score 1):

You should never install Python packages using `sudo` as it's a potential security risk. Instead, you should install packages in a virtual environment.

Here's how to create and activate a virtual environment using Python's built-in `venv` module.

## Creating the Environment

##### On Linux/Mac OS

```
$ python3 -m venv [name of environment]
```

##### On Windows

```
PS> python -m venv [name of environment]
```

## Activating the Environment

##### On Linux/Mac OS

```
$ source [name of environment]/bin/activate
```

##### On Windows

```
PS> [name of environment]\Scripts\activate
```

Once you have your virtual environment active you can install pandas using
`pip install pandas` and import it as usual in your program.

For more information on working with virtual environments read this: [How Can You Work With a Python Virtual Environment?](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/#how-can-you-work-with-a-python-virtual-environment)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference as the linked page may change.

Comment: I've edited the answer to provide more information.