# how to do pip install manually

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pycharm

i'm trying to run this code

```
pip install pandas
```

from my company laptop, but i think to have a firewall block. 
getting this error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pandas

I can't modify the firewall settings (in order to fix my problem) and i'm guessing if there is alternative way to download & install all libraries into python3.
Could i dowload the library and then paste it into a folder?
PS. i'm using pycharm

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768996/how-to-install-pandas-for-python-3 this might help

Comment: is not useful, pip install command does not work because of a firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Download appropriate file matching your Python version and architecture from https://pypi.org and then install it locally with pip, i.e.:

```
$ pip install --user pandas-0.25.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Processing ./pandas-0.25.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
...
```

Note that the package might require further dependencies, so you might need to repeat for different packages.

Comment: can you explain better? after download it there's a folder wher to paste it?

Comment: It does not matter where you save it. Just pass the path to the file to `pip install` command. In my specific example it was downloaded to current directory (whatever it was) and then installed from current directory. I might have used `pip install ./pandas-0.25.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl` or `pip install /path/to/pandas-0.25.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl` as well.

Comment: thx @raspy, but unfortunately i'm getting an error: pandas-0.25.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: my line code was: 'pip install C:/Users/indelicl/PycharmProjects/libraries/pandas-0.25.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl'

Comment: Please share output of `pip -V` and `python -VV`.

Answer (score 1):

If your machine requires a proxy, add this bit after install:

`--proxy=http://sub_domain_proxy.sub_domain.domain:port`