# Not able to install pandas in Ubuntu

Tags: python, pandas, pip, ubuntu-18.04

[image]

[image]

I have tried to install pandas by $pip install pandas.But still if I run a code that imports module pandas it shows an error as there is no module named pandas. But as I have shown in the second picture that $pip list shows there is a module pandas.Please help me ,so that I can install pandas successfully.My ubuntu version is 18.04.

Comment: How many python versions do you have? Could check you are installing pandas in the same version you are doing the import?

Comment: Perhaps try running `pip3 install pandas` or see the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768996/how-to-install-pandas-for-python-3

Comment: you probably have different python versions and try this: python -m pip install pandas(or if have python3, just type python3 instead of python)

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/ Text, please! Copy/paste from the terminal and properly format it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search.

Comment: @MDR pip3 install pandas works! Thanks..

Comment: @MDR , But I checked my python version by "$ python -V "outputs 2.7.. as I'm installing that module by pip3 command , so perhaps I was supposed to  use  python3. but how to view it in my terminal.

Comment: not sure.  perhaps have a rad around the subject of setting a specific version.  maybe: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410579/change-the-python3-default-version-in-ubuntu